# How should I query an integer where there are decimals in the data?

Tags: postgresql, comparison-operators

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE spent>= '1000'
```

This query still bring out numbers such as 598.99 and 230.909. My question is why is it doing this when I asked to search over or equal to 1000. Is there anyway to query so it only shows equal and more than 1000?

Comment: What data type is the column `spent`? Also: do not compare strings and numbers. `'1000'` is a string (character) constant. It is not a number constant. `1000` (without the single quotes) is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your `'1000'` is a text value. The other value is (or is converted to) text, too, so you end up with byte-per-byte comparison.

`598.99` is greater then `1000` because `5...` is greater then `1...`.

Cast to numeric types to do a proper comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE spent::numeric >= '1000'::numeric
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE spent::numeric >= 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You must compare numbers to get numeric comparison.

Use

```
WHERE CAST(spent AS numeric) >= 1000
```